# Where is "pause on exceptions" in Firefox 47?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, exception

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Settings) for Firefox advertises "Pause on Execptions" as a debugger option, but this appears to be missing form the Settings panel in Firefox 47. Where can I find it now?

EDIT: Here is my settings panel.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the debugger tab, there is a "debugger options" button where it has the options you see in the documentation.

[image]

You are clicking the wrong button. In the debugger tab there is another button like the one you are clicking:
[image: image 2]

Comment: That's the documentation I referred to, which differs from what I see in Firefox 47. I have edited my question to share the screenshot.

Comment: I am using Firefox 47. The button you are clicking is the wrong one. I updated my answer